# Polygon Artifacts Traversing Solid GIF

Tags: python

I've got a workflow that takes a Gif, converts it to a point cloud, smooths and meshes it using MeshLab and exports a bunch of Obj files. Every Obj contains the color geometry for some part of the image, the modelling is imprecise and there is overlap between some of the boundaries.

Using blender I walk through this solid with a camera using a ortho perspective. Because there is no lighting or advanced rendering I'm using Blender Render and shadeless materials. I think the artifacts are from rendering inside of objects. Towards the end of the solid (frame 170-180), the render start to look cleaner with minimal artifacts.
[image]

But for the rest of the traversal I have nasty artifacts like this. Here's the original Gif for reference.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fvu_Uiovm8a3lFbjhZdUotSkk/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone give me some insights on this?